# How to use InnerHtml on tag with specific Id

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I use visual studio 2013 and when try compile the webSite return me this error:

> BC30451: 'listaFornitori' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="style1" id="listaFornitori"  runat="server">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Prova</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Visual studio:**

```
'fornitoriHTML is a variable with html ul list create dynamically'
listaFornitori.InnerHtml = fornitoriHTML
```

Comment: Rename it to something different, save, rename it to `listaFornitori`, look if that fixed the problem.

Comment: I find problems even when I rename the id. After renamed on HTML, I do not find the id with autocompletion omn aspx.vb

Comment: Don't understand that because i have tested it with your aspx code and following was created automatically: `protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl listaFornitori;`. So your codebehind code compiles successfully. Close&Open Viusual Studio and recuild solution.

Comment: I closed and opened the solution but the error persists. I do not know where beat the head.

Comment: Using a backup version of the project. In the first start working properly. Stop debugging, restart and appears the error BC30451. How is it possible?